# How to get to print an item of a list in using curly braces {} in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is as follows and I want to print the value of x in the place of the curly braces in y.

```
x = ['abc']
y= "{0} college"
```

Comment: `print(y.format(x))`

Comment: Read up on [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = ['abc']
y= f"{x} college"
```

Note that in the example you gave, the output will be:

```
['abc'] college
```

because `x` is a list. If you want to have only 'abc' shown, then you could do:

```
x = 'abc'
y = f"{x} college"
```

**What's happening:** Since Python 3.6, you can format strings using this f-string syntax. You prepend the letter `f` to your string, then include any variables that you want to have printed inside the string inside curly braces `{}`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the f-strings (Formatted sting literals).

```
f'{x[0]} college' # To print the first index
```

From python3.8 you can use the `=` specifier in the f-strings, which are so handy when printing debug statements

```
f'{x[0]=} college' # prints x[0]='abc' college
```

Much nicer example from the [official python page](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

```
>>> print(f'{theta=}  {cos(radians(theta))=:.3f}')
theta=30  cos(radians(theta))=0.866
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using f-strings like below. You can see the PEP for this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals). You will need to ensure that you are using python 3.6 and above

```py
x = ['abc']
y= f'{x} college'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = ['abc']
y= "{0} college"

print(y.format(*x))
```

Outputs:

```py
abc college
```